# Expressing that something has been found in a literal source using only the name of the author

Tags: prepositions

If I have hit upon an interesting idea in a book by O'Henry and I want to say it briefly, how can I do this correctly?

1. I found it by O'Henry.
2. I found it at O'Henry.
3. I found it at O'Henry's.
4. I found it with O'Henry.
5. I fond it in O'Henry.
6. I found it in O'Henry's.

Comment: I'd use ***from*** if I had no other choice (probably, if it was "interesting", I'd say *I **got** it from O'Henry*). But usually, I'd expect to have the choice to write something a bit longer that would ***clearly*** express my intended meaning: *I found it **in a short story** by O'Henry,* for example. There's no "correct" preposition here - you're just trying to make the best of a bad job.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If not to expand the pattern, I can say: I found it from O'Henry. Thank you. One more question, please. Abiding by the same pattern but switching to a concrete person (my friend), I want to relate to my interlocutor that I found the key I had long been searching for in my friend's house. How can I say it: "I found the key at my friend's"? Or "I found the key at my friend"? Or "I found the key by my friend"? Or as you said: "I found the key from my friend?"

Comment: You ***find*** things ***at*** your ***friend's*** - you don't *have* to include an actual noun to associate with your friend (i.e. - his ***place*** or ***house***), but you always need the Saxon genitive ***'s*** in such constructions. On the other hand, you ***get*** things ***from*** your ***friend*** (no possessive if he gave you something).

Comment: Do you mean [O. Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O._Henry)?

Comment: Yes, of course. I mean William Sidney Porter. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

These are all a bit odd to my ears.

Sometimes a textbook will become well known by the name(s) of its authors.  For example a popular textbook on A-level maths is know as "Bostock and Chandler" because its title "Mathematics for Advanced Level" doesn't clearly identify it.  In this case you could say "I found the problem in Bostock and Chandler" (*Spivak* is another example)

But O Henry doesn't identify a particular book or story.  And fictional works usually have a proper title. So you could say

> I found it in *The Gift of the Magi*.

If you don't want to identify the particular story (for whatever reason)

> I found it in the works of O Henry.